# can not open windows form from dynamic treeview in c sharp

Tags: treeview

I have a question and that is i have successfully generate treeview list from database in c sharp. parent and child node is fine. the problem is who can i call the respective form from clicking the node. the form names are stored in database. is there any way to do that. i am new to treeview control`

```
        string qry = "select * from payroll_forms where level_id='100'";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
        DataTable dt_child = new DataTable(); ;
        SqlDataAdapter adp_child;
        adp.Fill(dt);
        TreeNode childnode = null;
        string qry_child = string.Empty;
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dt_child.Clear();
                parentnode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(dt.Rows[i]["form_caption"].ToString());
                qry_child = "select * from payroll_forms where level_id !=100 and parent_id='" + dt.Rows[i]["form_no"] + "'";
                adp_child = new SqlDataAdapter(qry_child, con);
                adp_child.Fill(dt_child);
                if (dt_child.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt_child.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        childnode = parentnode.Nodes.Add(dt_child.Rows[j]["form_caption"].ToString());


                    }
                }
            }`
```